# Determining that a generator is open or closed

Tags: php

How does one determine whether a generator has been run in PHP without changing the state of the generator?

Code example: What goes in the function `is_open` to make this code run without throwing an exception?

```
function is_open(\Generator $generator):bool {
    // WHAT GOES HERE?
}

function sample_generator_1() {
    yield 'blah';
}

// Force PHP to make the closure an empty generator.
function sample_generator_2() {
    if (false) yield 'blah';
}

$g1 = sample_generator_1();
assert(is_open($g1));
foreach($g1 as $item) {} // drain the generator
assert(!is_open($g1));

$g2 = sample_generator_2();
assert(is_open($g2));
foreach($g2 as $item) {} // drain the generator
assert(!is_open($g2));
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/generator.valid.php

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried but, as a first approximation you would like something like this:

```
function is_closed(\Generator $generator):bool {
return !$generator->valid();
}
```

as the php online manual say: https://www.php.net/manual/en/generator.valid.php

When a generator function is called, a new object of the internal Generator class is returned. That class signature (https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.generator.php) has a valid method that return false if the generator is closed, true otherwise.

Since the standard class method, I would have leveraged on it directly, but I understand it is a matter of taste:

```
$g = sample_generator();
assert($g->valid()); // MUST NOT throw exception
foreach($g as $item) {} // drain the generator
assert(!$g->valid()); // MUST throw exception
```

Comment: you must use $g->valid(), sandbox: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/29845c78136835000f240032abefc31375444de3

Comment: @jspit Thank you, I will update the answer. I followed the signature in the php manual and in php 7.2.4 instance I had readily available it worked. It works either ways in that version.

Comment: As a strangest behaviour is that a different online parser give different result https://onecompiler.com/php/3xf6v2gv7 , but it is php, you know

Comment: I'm not sure I can accept this as an answer because it has been documented that `valid` doesn't work as expected when the generator is empty. Add `if (false)` before  `yield 'blah';` and see where the exception occurs. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77515.

Comment: Here's the use case that prompted this question: I was getting the "trying to traverse a closed generator" exception. If I attempted to trap this exception with `assert($g->valid())`, it would break my code when I gave it an empty generator.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure an iterable is given, such as

```
foreach (ensure_iterator($subject) as $item) ...
```

Where the function always returns either the (valid) `$subject` or an empty array.

For instance:

```
function iterates(iterable $subject): bool {
    return $subject instanceof \Generator
        ? $subject->valid()
        : count($subject) > 0;
}

function ensure_iterator(?iterable $subject): iterable {
    return $subject !== null && iterates($subject) ? $subject : [];
}
```

https://3v4l.org/cm1PV

Comment: Pay attention to the bottom of the fiddle, where the exception is thrown in the last (non-ensured) block of `foreach`'s.